# How do I launch JemmyFXBrowser?

Tags: jemmyfx

I acquired and built JemmyFX and JemmyFXBrowser from http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/tests/, but I cannot figure out how to launch it.  From directory `tests/tools/Jemmy`, I first tried:

```
$ java -jar JemmyFXBrowser/dist/JemmyFXBrowser.jar
```

But this produces exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jemmy/timing/State
```

Then I tried adding all the `*.jars` to the classpath like so:

```
$ java -cp ./JemmyFX/dist/JemmyFX.jar:./GlassRobot/dist/GlassRobot.jar:./GlassImage/dist/GlassImage.jar:./jemmy_core/JemmySupport.jar:./jemmy_core/JemmyAWTInput.jar:./jemmy_core/JemmyBrowser.jar:./jemmy_core/JemmyCore.jar:./jemmy_core/junit.jar -jar ./JemmyFXBrowser/dist/JemmyFXBrowser.jar
```

But this produces the very same exception mentioned above.  So, I exploded the `JemmyFXBrowser.jar` to discover the name of the main class and tried this:

```
$ java -cp ./JemmyFX/dist/JemmyFX.jar:./GlassRobot/dist/GlassRobot.jar:./GlassImage/dist/GlassImage.jar:./jemmy_core/JemmySupport.jar:./jemmy_core/JemmyAWTInput.jar:./jemmy_core/JemmyBrowser.jar:./jemmy_core/JemmyCore.jar:./jemmy_core/junit.jar:./JemmyFXBrowser/dist/JemmyFXBrowser.jar org.jemmy.fx.Browser
```

This results in a couple of exceptions.  First, this one:

```
Exception in thread "FX app launch thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

And then this one, over and over again:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
```

Clearly, I am missing something very fundamental here, but I can find no documentation anywhere on how this app is supposed to be launched, and it has no built-in help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very next argument should be the main class of the application you want to test.  We must also add our application `*.jar` (or `*.jars`) to the classpath.

```
$ java -cp ./JemmyFX/dist/JemmyFX.jar:./GlassRobot/dist/GlassRobot.jar:./GlassImage/dist/GlassImage.jar:./jemmy_core/JemmySupport.jar:./jemmy_core/JemmyAWTInput.jar:./jemmy_core/JemmyBrowser.jar:./jemmy_core/JemmyCore.jar:./jemmy_core/junit.jar:./JemmyFXBrowser/dist/JemmyFXBrowser.jar:./MyApplication.jar org.jemmy.fx.Browser my.MainClass
```